# How to implement rabbitmq in angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amqp

I am using node js resful api and amqp to handle the api requests. The rabbitMQ is working fine in Node js but its not possible in angular js. How can I implement amqp in client side angular js script.

Comment: why do you want to expose `rabbitmq` to client directly through `angular.js`? Better consume the backend rabbitmq wrapper through `websocket` or `apis` ?

Comment: Now i am try to use send request part in client side angular js.

Comment: Would you please explain how to use it through api.?

Comment: I tried the Browserify method but create connection is not working.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the web-stomp plugin. But its not good idea, use rabbitmq from angular, its not safe way

https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html